# Split revenue in CRM between multiple resources.

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-online

If the owner of the opportunity is responsible for 70% of the proposed revenue, and one team member is responsible for the other 30%, we would like to see their respective pipelines reflect their contributions.  Currently the owner receives 100% of the proposed revenue in their pipeline. Is there another way to manage this within the base CRM product?. If not, our thoughts were to add a column in the sales team entry function for "split"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know CRM lacks any native "split" functionality, so you are on the right track to build it yourself. On your sales team entity you can add the split % field and then choose a way to do the necessary math. 
Options could include:

Out-of-box calculated fields.

JavaScript (will only work on the form, not for imported or integrated records)

Business rules

Use a workflow tools add-on such as [Aiden Kaskela's Workflow Elements](https://kaskelasolutions.com/) or  [Jason Lattimer's Numeric Workflow Utilities](https://github.com/jlattimer?tab=repositories). [Andrew Butenko's Ultimate Workflow Toolkit](http://butenko.pro/ultimate-workflow-toolkit/) has some very useful things but I'm not sure if has a math module.

Write your own custom workflows or plugins to do the math.

One piece of logic you'll need is to ensure that the split across the sales team totals 100%.

Comment: i used calculated fields to calculate percentage of amount entered from total established revenue. thank you!